# Script compiled with Nuitka, raises Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, python-2.7, shared-libraries, .so, nuitka

I have a script 'test.py' which imports some '.so' modules and depends upon them. the '.so' modules are present inside a folder 'COMPILED' whose absolute path I've added to PYTHONPATH environment variable. So, now when I run it - "$ python test.py" - it runs great. And when I compile it using Nuitka - "$ nuitka --recurse-all test.py" - it compiles too and produces a 'test.exe' executable, now when I execute it instead of importing the module and running normally it raises a 'Segmentation Fault'

And Lastly, I'd like to add that I have generated the '.so' files using Nuitka too - they're basically modules. They work like a dream with normal uncompiled python, but as soon as I compile test.py with Nuitka.... KABOOM!

**THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN POSTED BEFORE:**

But It has not been answered  and I could not comment or notify someone there, because I've just created my account, so I have asked it again. Here's the link to the previously asked version:
[python package complied with nuitka fails with segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847499/python-package-complied-with-nuitka-fails-with-segmentation-fault?rq=1)

```
Directory Structure:
/PARENT_FOLDER
|______/COMPILED: <---- this folder contains all the '.so' files
|       file1.so
|       file2.so
|       .
|       .
|______test.py    <---- here is the test.py script
```

Comment: A SIGSEGV can be caused by many things, just because a previous question was raised with the same issue does not mean the same cause.   Without the source I doubt anyone can answer this.  Personally I would try to track the fault in the C++ then work back from there.  Look at the core dump using `gdb`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't know C++, try to reduce the `test.py` code to isolate the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the responses @cdarke :). I'm very sorry, but I did not mention that the author on the previous question, commented on one of the answers that he has solved the problem, but he did not mention how. That is why I asked.  I'll give gdb a try though. Peace!

Comment: Did you try contacting the author yourself?

Comment: Yes! I contacted him, I even posted the solution that works for me on the bug list. Mr Kay - the author - says that my solution is pure luck, and that I should not rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! so my problem has been solved. Turns out that it was some issue with memory layout and stuff I got some hints from here:
  http://www.freelists.org/post/nuitka-dev/Building-modules-separately-from-the-main-application,3

The page basically says that using clang with nuitka instead of gcc removes the segfault. I was going to try that, but I randomly typed in "nuitka --help" and came across this option "--lto(link time optimizations)". I thought of giving it a try - note, according to --help this requires g++ -  so instead of running

```
nuitka --recurse-all test.py
```

I ran

```
nuitka --lto test.py
```

and the resulting binary executes just fine with no 'segmentation faults'. I also ran

```
nuitka --recurse-all --lto test.py
```

that works too - in case you're wondering. This has also been reported as a bug on the Nuitka bug list:

http://bugs.nuitka.net/issue238?@ok_message=msg%201799%20created%0Aissue%20238%20messages%20edited%20ok&@template=item

Environment:

Nuitka version: 0.5.18

gcc version: 4.8.4

Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on intel corei5

Comment: For Nuitka 0.7, use --lto=yes instead.